# Swift Missing tabbaritem image

Tags: xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I got a problem with a UITabBarController. When i load a uitabbarcontroller with this piece of code:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It works well but my only problem is the tabbaritem image.. The first one shows up normally but the second one (got two tabbar items) doesn't want to show.. Only after a couple of seconds.

Tabcontroller and tabbaritems are made in the storyboard. Not programmatically

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Comment: Check the image, is it a very big file?

Comment: @JoeBenton nope.. its a png with size 52x52. only 3-4KB

Comment: Are you saying it takes a couple of seconds for it to show, or it disappears after a couple of seconds?

Comment: @JoeBenton It takes a couple of seconds to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue was iOS 9.2.. Updated my iPad to iOS 9.3.1 and it was fixed